# Kivy Reset Focus After on_text_validation Deactivates It

Tags: python, focus, kivy, textinput

Looking for another tip to get the focus to return back to the original TextInput area `answer`.

Here's what I tried:

```
def setPracPopBtns(instance):
    if (instance.id == "sbt") and (answer.text != ""):
        # Make lots of irrelevant changes, and then...
        answer.font_name = myTrgF
        answer.text = unicode("")
        answer.focus = True # This does not return the focus.

# Set the answer TextInput area as the focus.
def setAnswerFocus(self):
    answer.focus = True
    # This only works on the initial load of the popup.
    # That's to be expected. The popup never reopens.

# Build the essential practice layout/widget.
# Define the elements.
practice = BoxLayout(orientation="vertical")
answer = TextInput(id="sbt", multiline=False, size_hint=(.8, .5), text="")
answer.bind(text=lambda instance, text: setattr(sbtLen, "text", str(len(text)) + "/" + ansLen.text),
            on_text_validate=setPracPopBtns)
# Lots of irrelevant formatting things to build practice.
# Load practice into the pracPop.
pracPop = Popup(on_open=setAnswerFocus, title_align="center", content=practice)
```

Will I have to develop a whole focus path, or is there some neater way of getting the focus back to the original TextInput area?

So to clarify, this is what happens:

1. A popup called `pracPop` opens.
2. The `setAnswerFocus` function correctly places the focus on a
3. TextInput area called `answer`. A user hits Enter to submit text, triggering `on_text_validate=setPracPopBtns`.
4. `answer` loses its focus. Resetting the focus with `answer.focus = True` does nothing.

(4) is the problem for which I have not yet found the solution.

Comment: Going to the point, explain yourself better, I recommend reading [ask], I do not understand anything. :D

Comment: I edited it to clarify as best I could. There's about 100 lines of code between these two things, none of which do anything with focus, so I clipped it, which is why you see lots of variables that have no apparent references. They're not really relevant to the poblem at hand.